# write UWP app using json-like formatting

Tags: json, xaml, uwp

XAML uses XML-like formatting.
Is there editor that will allow user to write and read XAML code in JSON-like formatting (or some addon to VS) 
It can be saved and read to XML - but during editing it would be nice to see it more eye friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want XAML to look like JSON, then probably not. XAML is just XML.

There are couple of plugins which can reformat XAML according to rules you set, including [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). But they don't display it as a different format.

You can also use the visual designer alone without touching/seeing any code, but from my experience this is not the best idea. I get the best results if I code the XAML by hand and use the visual designer only to visualize the result without running the application.

Creating such plugin would take a huge amount of time and you would have a lot of problems to solve. The problems would probably outweigh the benefits.